# Нужно ли переопределять MarshalByRefObject.InitializeLifetimeService при работе с плагинами?

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-remoting, плагин

Есть у меня такая штука: https://github.com/Modus-Exciter/RW.Ring/blob/master/source/Notung/Services/OperationLauncherProxy.cs

Она позволяет запускать задачи с отображением прогресса операции в других доменах. Она работает, но я не уверен, что две обёртки над задачей, унаследованные от `MarshalByRefObject` - это оптимальное решение. Возможно, это можно оптимизировать, переопределив метод `InitializeLifetimeService`. Возможно, переопределив ещё и `CreateObjRef`, тоже можно сделать более элегантное решение.

Но нужно ли это делать, если это у меня случай не распределённого приложения, а просто несколько доменов в одном процессе? В книгах по .NET Remoting обычно все эти вопросы разбираются, когда речь идёт о клиент-серверной архитектуре, но это вроде как устаревшая технология, однако для взаимодействия двух доменов приложения всё равно ничего другого нет. Точнее, есть `System.AddIn`, но судя по тому, что написано в документации, использовать этот оторванный от жизни набор абстракций не стоит.

А с лизингом и спонсорами всё понятно, кроме одного: применимо ли это в локальных приложениях, или только в распределённых?

Comment: Исходите из необходимого и достаточного. Сконцентрируйтесь на задаче, которую вы решаете, быть может домены вам вовсе не нужны, вы не указали, что у вашего приложения есть исполняемые плагины, для которых требуются ограничения доступа к операциям. Охотитьтся за оптимизацией и паттернами можно бесконечно, но чем глубже копать, тем меньше толку.

Comment: Поскольку проект не коммерческий, меня интересует именно совершенство. Оно и так работает, теперь хочется по максимуму отрезать всё лишнее. Я сделал поддержку доменов именно для приличия, чтобы не стыдно было выкладывать на Github. Для лично моих задач достаточно плагинов в текущем домене, ни выгружать их в ходе работы, ни ограничивать операции мне вроде не нужно. Но раз уж я взялся за эту тему, хочу дойти до 100% понимания.

Comment: В таком случае ваш проект может оказаться неоправданно перегружен сложными решениями. Я например недавно выкинул половине `async/await`ов из проекта, тем самым сократил его код на 10% и потребение памяти на столько же. А было совершенно и элегантно сделано. А всё потому что в тех местах, где я убрал, в асинхронности не было необходимости. То же самое про домены. Инструменты должны применяться там, где это оправдано и необходимо, а то может получиться так, что код студента, написанный на примитивных паттернах может оказаться эффективнее вашего. На ваш вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: ...пробуйте, тестируйте, профилируйте процессор и память. Смотрите, что лучше работает, то и выбирайте.